# Link to controller index with certain id fails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to make a back link that will link to the controller index.

```
<%= link_to 'Back', employee_personals_path%>
```

It works.
But in index i want to send user id also.

```
 <%= link_to 'Back', {  :action => "index", :user_id => @user_id},
   {:class=>"btn btn-success"}%>
```

This works. 
Now i want to implement sending user_id by first method

```
<%= link_to 'Back', employee_personals_path, :user_id => @user_id%>
```

But it does not works. How can i make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a parameter to your employee_personals_path function (not to link_to):

```
<%= link_to 'Back', employee_personals_path(:user_id => @user_id) %>
```

Comment: I have like this issue in my update controller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037524/format-of-redirect-is-wrong-in-rails  I hope you can answer it]