# Format of redirect is wrong in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I want to send a `:user_id` to my index controller when it redirects:

```
format.html { redirect_to @employee_personal, notice: 'Personal was successfully updated.'}
```

In my index controller I have to send:

```
@user_id = @employee_personal.user_id
```

variable.

How can I send this? In the redirect I tried:

```
format.html { redirect_to @employee_personal(:user_id => @user_id), notice: 'Personal was successfully updated.' }
```

It is wrong.

```
format.html { redirect_to :action => :index, :user_id => @user_id  }
```

is right.

How can I make that error right in that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
format.html { redirect_to @employee_personal, user_id: @user_id, notice: 'Personal was successfully updated.'}
```

Also, you can specify the path with params, something like this:

```
format.html { redirect_to employee_personal_path(@employee_personal, user_id: @user_id), notice: 'Personal was successfully updated.'}
```